# Insert a space between two variables

Tags: php

I have a problem to add space and comma between two variables:

```
<td><?php echo '<a href=https://www.google.de/maps/place/
'.$row['ort'].$row['strasse'].' target="_blank">'.$row['ort'].'</a>';?></td>
```

The results is

```
BerlinKolnerweg
```

but I want to insert space and comma like this:

```
Berlin, Kolnerweg
```

This does not work:

```
.$row['ort'].', ' .$row['strasse'].
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Because not work, you got any errors?

Comment: Please elaborate on why `.$row['ort'].', ' .$row['strasse'].` doesn't work... because it should.

Comment: Google Maps has a problem with displaying.

Comment: While after

    .$row['ort'].', ' .$row['strasse'].

output is

    Berlin,

The second variable is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a space (escaped as %20) and a comma in the url. I moved the php into the anchor-tag instead of echoing out the whole thing. Try if this works:

```
<a href="https://www.google.de/maps/place/<?php echo $row['ort'].',%20'.$row['strasse']; ?>" target="_blank">
    <?php echo $row['ort'].', '.$row['strasse']; ?>
</a>
```

Comment: Finally enough to fill the space with entities &nbsp;
Trivial matter. :)
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<td>
   <a href=https://www.google.de/maps/place/<?php echo $row['ort'].$row['strasse']; ?>' target="_blank">
       <?php echo $row['ort'].", ".$row['strasse']; ?>
   </a>
</td>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, but to no avail.
Now is in Table "Berlin, Kolnerweg", but when i clicked on link, Google Maps result is "BerlinKolnerweg". 
In Table suffice "Berlin", important is result for Google.